# How to apply a patch to drupal core using a drush make

Tags: makefile, drupal, patch, drush

I'm in the process of a disassembling of a live drupal based site. While writing a drush make file I discovered there was some patching of contrib modules and core. I can instruct drush make to patch contrib modules using a 'patch' option. But I can't make it patch core.

I tried both

```
projects[drupal][patch][] = ...
projects[core][patch][] = ...
```

without success, nothing changes.

Can someone give a hint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems as though you are on the right track. Here's what I use, which runs and patches correctly:

```
core = "6.x"
api = "2"

projects[drupal][type] = "core"
projects[drupal][version] = "6.28"
projects[drupal][patch][] = "http://drupalcode.org/project/openatrium.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/master:/robots_txt_rollback.patch"
```

Comment: sorry for long reply. Your solution works, thanks! Looks like mine should worked too, but I tried to apply an incorrect patch.